# how to access firestore collection dynamically, if i dont know the doc name in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a category collections with subcategory products. I know that i can access docs and collection like this:
`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('prova').doc('ths67hsehjead58').collection('products').snapshots()`, but what if user will create his own categories, and i will not know the collection's doc etc..?

Until now, i can manage to bring the category name [index] to the new screen `final String document`, but i'm not able to access each categorie's products.

I have tried with `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('prova').doc(widget.document).collection('products').snapshots()`, but it does not works.

```
 class CategoriesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String document;

  const CategoriesPage({Key? key, required this.document}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CategoriesPage> createState() => _CategoriesPageState();
}

   class _CategoriesPageState extends State<CategoriesPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.document),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.edit_note_outlined), onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> CategoryInfo()));
          },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('prova').doc(widget.document).collection('products').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());{
            final document = snapshot.data?.docs;
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: document!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
```